# Puppeteer: How can I pass a text into an evaluate function?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer, and I want to import and use the following function.

```
async function getTextExceptChild(page, selector) {
    const text = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        const element = document.querySelector(sel);
        return element ? element.textContent.trim() : null;
    }, selector);
    return text;
}
```

```
const selector = 'a > strong';
console.log(await getTextExceptChild(timeItem, selector));
```

But when I use it, I get an error. I don't know why.

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLLIElement]' is not a valid selector.
```

I've also changed the variable names passed to evaluate() to not overlap, but to no avail.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `sel` is not a selector, it's an html element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your case your sel is actually [object HTMLLIElement] (I don't see any reference in provided code to this type).

Anyway, you can try to init element via puppeteer first as

```js
async function getTextExceptChild(page, selector) {
    const textElement = await page.$(selector); // use waitForSelector if you don't expect that element can not to exist
    const text = await page.evaluate((e) => {
        return e ? e.textContent.trim() : null;
    }, textElement);
    return text;
```

Comment: I modified the code to the following and passed the selector text `'a > strong'` as an argument, but it still incorrectly identifies the text as an HTMLElement object.
The strange thing is that if I run this code as is in the main code, without functionalizing it, it doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: I got an answer from gpt. `const text = await elementHandle.evaluate((e, s) => {...}, selector)` solved the problem.